# Styling attributes with AJAX data post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using jQuery to get all content from a div including its child elements.

DIV content:

```
<div class="content">
   <h1 style="color:red">Test Title</h1>
   <p style="color:blue">Test Description</p>
</div>
```

Collecting the data in a new variable using the below jQuery:

```
emailContent = $( ".content" ).html();
```

Then I am creating an AJAX post as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl, 
    data: {
        "action": "action1",
        "emailContent":emailContent

    }
});
```

I am using the content to send an email using the `wp_mail()` function, however once the email is sent all styling is being ignored.

The wp_mail function is coded this way:

```
$to = 'xx@xx.com';
    $subject = 'Subject';
    $message = $_POST['emailContent'];
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

When I changed the Content-type to text/plain, the following is the output:

```
<div class=\"emailContent\">    <h1 style=\"color:red\">Test Title</h1>    <p style=\"color:blue\">Test Description</p> </div>
```

Can the slashes be the reason for not being formatted good when the type is HTML ?

Any ideas on how I can retain the inline styling when sending the data over the AJAX post ?

Comment: can you post what you are getting in email?

Comment: The style attributes are definitely included in the string, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/pr051kw4/. If it's being stripped out it's either due to the email sending library you're using, or the email client is ignoring it. The latter is very likely as CSS in emails is incredibly hit and miss. When it comes to HTML in an email you need to imagine it's 1997 and you're writing for your content to be seen in IE3.

Comment: HTML mail - in particular its styling - is a minefield and is a specialist field in itself. Many e-mail clients will strip out some or all styling if the message isn't configured a certain way (or sometimes even if it is.) You may want to look into a service such as SendInBlue to send templated mail that way.

Comment: You mention wp_mail, have you set the content type to HTML? Otherwise it might be stripping your HTML out
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/#description

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know that HTML emails are really fussy and you need to think old school, however it's only colours that i'm testing and still not working.

Comment: @AhmadAsjad - The email data is correct, simply no styling

Comment: @TMitchell Yes, I updated the post and as you can see I am setting it as HTML in the header

Comment: I think you should use text/plain as email formatting or all html will be formated in the email and you will never know the classes/styles

Comment: @cralfaro - I changed to plain and the result is as follows: `<div class=\"emailContent\">
   <h1 style=\"color:red\">Test Title</h1>
   <p style=\"color:blue\">Test Description</p>
</div>`

Comment: @yousafMazunkig what is your expected result?

Comment: @yousafMazunkig i think what you need is escape the text content before to send it

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding `stripslashes()` to the `$message` content and now styling is being applied.